# How to display REST API response in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Front-end dev, and I want to display below REST API response using Vue.js
Where the domains names will be a DDL, once u select one of them it will show u the list of subdomain in it with their version.

```
[
  {
    "subdomains": [
      {
        "name": "subdomain-1",
        "version": "0.4.12"
      },
      {
        "name": "subdomain-2",
        "version": "0.4.25"
      }
    ],
    "name": "RB"
  },
  {
    "subdomains": [
      {
        "name": "subdomain-3",
        "version": "0.4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "subdomain-4",
        "version": "0.4.5"
      }
    ],
    "name": "OB"
  }
]
```